# Is the Moon's orbital plane angle relative to the ecliptic constant?

Tags: the-moon, orbit, precession

I've come across a number of sources ([example](https://www.space.com/how-total-solar-eclipse-2024-will-differ-from-2017-solar-eclips)) saying some variation of this:

> The moon's orbital path around Earth is tilted by 5.1 degrees with respect to the orbit of the Earth around the sun.

This isn't strictly true though, right? Per [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_standstill), the angle of the moon's orbit varies by something like +/-5 degrees. So really we should say "The moon's orbital path around Earth is tilted by ***up to*** 5.1 degrees".

Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: I think you're misreading the lunar standstill article. It's just saying that the Moon's ~5.1° inclination to the ecliptic (which is inclined by ~23.5° to the equator) means that the Moon's maximum declination range varies over the nodal precession cycle from ±(23.5°-5.1°) to ±(23.5+5.1°). I have some info on the lunar declination & standstill here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/50974/16685 That answer is in response to a kind of complicated question, so some of the info & graphs may be a little confusing. ;)

Comment: The Moon's inclination to the ecliptic varies from ~5° to ~5.3° in a rather complicated way. I have graphs of the inclination and other lunar orbital elements here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55112/16685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.

The angle of the Moon's orbital plane with respect to the ecliptic is fairly constant at ~5.1° with a bit of variation as pointed out by @PM2Ring in their comment. The orbit and the plane defined by it does not change (much).

Over the duration of one month the Moon moves along its orbit. Thus its *position* changes during these days from a position about 5.1 degrees below the ecliptic to on on the ecliptic 7 days later to one 5.1 degrees above 14 days later - and back to -5.1° when the orbit is completed one month later.

Thus:

The Moon's *orbital path* around Earth is tilted *by* 5.1 degrees.

The Moon's *position* varies *up to* 5.1 degrees below and above the ecliptic.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a correct understanding?

Not exactly. The Sun is a huge perturber of the Moon's orbit. From a heliocentric perspective, the gravitational acceleration of the Moon toward the Sun is over twice that of the Moon toward the Earth. From a geocentric perspective, the Sun is still a huge huge perturber of the Moon's orbit about the Earth. It wasn't until the early 20th century that a fairly accurate description of the Moon's orbit was developed, primarily due to this huge perturbation. The other planets and the Earth's not-quite spherical shape also perturb the Moon's orbit, but to a much lesser extent than the Sun.

That said, the inclination of the Moon's orbit with respect to the ecliptic is fairly constant. Below is a plot of the Moon's instantaneous (osculating) inclination:

[image: Lunar orbit inclination for 2008 to 2010]
<sub>Source: [Eclipses and the Moon's orbit](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEhelp/moonorbit.html) at nasa.gov</sub>

Note that the inclination varies from less than 5.0° to about 5.3°, with a mean of 5.145°. So, not quite constant, but still, fairly constant.